# Active Directory : How to access AD remotely over SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

Dears, I am working on a task, this task makes operations on `Active Directory LDAP` using `java`, the `code` is ok the certificate status is ok regarding to this link [configuring-an-ssl-connection-to-active-directory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-an-ssl-connection-to-active-directory-229838458.html)

But : I run the code it gives `java.net.SocketException connection reset` on the  connection `ldaps://ip:636` , I did the following workarounds:

1. I used `Apache Studio` , and `LdapAdmin` and `ldp.exe` the connection is opened on port `389` but the server is down on `636`.
2. `telnet` between the two machines and ports are open on `636`.
3. I typed `netstat` and the result `389` no mentions for `636`.

How to enable remote access for Active directory over `ssl` to access `ldaps://ip:636` from anywhere ?

Comment: what is the problem i need to post an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to enable LDAPS on an Active Directory server: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and i solved it , but still i don't know what is the relationship

the problem in my `certificate` in the `ROOT`
When i created the `CA` i `logged in` with `non-admin` `user` and i created the `CA` it was avoid me to choose `Enterprise` `option` in `setup type` it forced me to choose `StandAlone` option ,
i deleted it and `logged in` as `Administrator` and i created new `CA` choose it `Enterprise` and defined it in certification for `AD` using  `MMC` and i run the `service` again it is running successfully.